# opening stream using a 2d array

Tags: c++

Can anyone fix this sample code that will print a file in 2D array. Here is the code and the output.

```
while (!file.eof())
{ 
   int counter =0;
   file>>n;

   cout<< setw(4)<< n << "  ";     

   if (counter == 5)
   {         
       cout << endl; 
       counter = 0;
       counter ++;
       }  

   }
}
```

The output is not in table form.

The output is:

Index  Size  Weight  (lb/ft)  Diameter  (in)     0     2  0.167  0.250     1     3  0.376  0.375     2     4  0.668  0.500     3     5  1.043  0.625     4     7  1.502  0
     6     9  2.670  1.000     7    12  3.400  1.128     8    14  4.303  1.270  1.270

Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: You are setting `counter = 0` at the top of every iteration of the loop, so it will never reach 5... Move the definition of your `counter` variable to before the loop... Also, you're only ever incrementing it if it's already 5, so there's another reason it will never reach 5...

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

Define `coutner` as static

```
while (!file.eof())
{ 
   static int counter =0;
   file>>n;

   cout<< setw(4)<< n << "  ";     

   if (counter == 5)
   {         
       cout << endl; 
       counter = 0;
       counter ++;
       }  

   }
}
```

or have it define external to the while loop:

```
int counter = 0;

while (!file.eof())
{ 

   file>>n;

   cout<< setw(4)<< n << "  ";     

   if (counter == 5)
   {         
       cout << endl; 
       counter = 0;
       counter ++;
       }  

   }
}
```

If you define it and initialized it to 0 in ever iteratoin of the while loop - it will never reach 5 to print `endl;`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that not only the counter is initialized in every loop, as others pointed out before me, but moreover, it is never actually increased. The only increase I see is within the condition that it is equal to five. As it is never increased outside the condition, it never reaches five (even if it is declared as static or outside the loop), hence the condition is never met.

You have an uneven number of opening and closing curly braces, too.

I am not exactly sure what you want to achieve. If you want a line break after every fifth iteration, the following should work:

```
int counter = 0;
cout << setw(4) // suffice to set once

while (!file.eof())
{ 
   file >> n;

   cout << n << "  ";

   if (++counter == 5) // increase here before checking condition
   {         
       cout << endl; 
       counter = 0;
       // do not increase here again
   }
}
```